# Stop Event in IE 9 (without upgrading to Prototype 1.7)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs

The site I'm working on uses Prototype 1.6.1. Its Event.stop() doesn't work in IE9. I know that Prototype 1.7 fixes the problem. However, is there a  walk-around if I cannot upgrade to Prototype 1.7?

I need the site to be compatible with IE 7, 8 and 9 (as well as Chrome, Firefox, etc).

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried `event.preventDefault()` and it doesn't work for me in IE 9. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/garthcn/AdR7g/
It works in jsfiddle/Chrome/Firefox. If you paste the code to an HTML file and open it with IE9, it won't work.

EDIT2: I just found that Prototype 1.6.1 adds its own `preventDefault()` method to IE which doesn't work on IE 9. However, IE 9 comes with its own `preventDefault()` which actually works. So if I stick to Prototype 1.6.1, I guess I cannot get `preventDefault()` to work on IE 9.

Comment: You could always compare the 1.7 and 1.6.1 Event.stop() code to see what the IE9-fix was, and replicate it in your version.

Comment: @Marc B I stepped into the `Event.stop()` method of Prototype 1.7. It seems that it just calls `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. Besides, these two methods are not part of Prototype. However, if I call them explicitly with Prototype 1.6.1, the event still won't stop. I'm sure I missed something but I didn't find out what it is. Thanks!

Comment: @garthcn: Prototype overrides those methods in IE. Perhaps this is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
function stopDefAction(evt) {
     evt = evt || event;
     if (evt.preventDefault) {
          evt.preventDefault();
     }
     else {
          evt.returnValue = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.  This seems to be simply what the internal implementation of preventDefault is doing, so... kind of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like internally Prototype does extend, which - under IE9 - breaks things.  Without upgrading, the *easy* thing would be to add an x-ua-compatible meta tag at the tippy top of your head tag (but below the charset tag) to force IE9 into being IE less than 9.

If you have the ability, you could also try patching Prototype directly:
http://mandagreen.com/prototype-1-6-event-stop-ie9-quick-patch/
This was written for 1.6.0, but I think it should work for 1.6.1.  I have the same problem and will likely be trying it out to see what happens.

Comment: The only way I could find around this was to use a different library.  We're currently migrating to jQuery, so we run it in noConflict mode and I was able to wire the submit handler with that and let the rest of the submit handler code be run as is