# stopping form submit with prototype.js

Tags: javascript, forms, prototypejs

There seems to be a issue or my lack of knowledge how to stop the form to be submitted with prototypejs. Maybe someone can help me with the issue I'm facing

consider this simple form

```
<form id="formContact" method="post">
    <p>Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="name" name="yourName" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p>E-mail:
        <br />
        <input type="e-mail" name="yourEmail" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p>Message:
        <br />
        <textarea cols="20" rows="10" name="yourMessage"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit this form" name="submitButton" />
    </p>
</form>
```

and this little js snippet from protoype manual http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/stop/

```
Event.observe('formContact', 'submit', function (event) {
    var login = $F('name').strip();
    if ('' == login) {
        Event.stop(event);
        // Display the issue one way or another
    }
});

$('formContact').submit();
```

all this in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/C3eFu/2/

now the issue here is it stops the form perfectly if button is clicked but not when form is submitted with javascript.? 
is this the 1% where prototype fails to stop the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a lot of Googleing apparently the onsubmit event is not fired on the form when the `.submit()` method is called. This is not a lack of PrototypeJS but more a behavior that has not been fixed in Javascript.

You can make your code behave the way you want it to happen by calling the `onsubmit` handler and then watching if the event is stopped and then decide to fire the submit `method()`

Comment: this can be done with jquery without any issues so i think it fires , let me see if i can make a example

Comment: see this fiddle that uses jQuery that can handle this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/zTLC6/

Comment: those are 2 different `submit()` methods - in your first fiddle with PrototypeJS the `submit()` method being called is the actual form object method - vs the second fiddle with jQuery the `submit()` method is a jQuery method that eventually fires the actual form object method. And FWIW in the jQuery fiddle the events that fired were reverse of the comments in the js.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` then capture the click event of the button instead, or you can capture the submit event:

```
function stopDefAction(evt) {
     evt = evt || event;
     if (evt.preventDefault) {
          evt.preventDefault();
     }
     else {
          evt.returnValue = false;
     }
}
```

See: [Stop Event in IE 9 (without upgrading to Prototype 1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291805/stop-event-in-ie-9-without-upgrading-to-prototype-1-7)

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the source but I can include javascript so this is not a way to solve my current issue. It can be done with jquery tho. I'll keep searching.

Comment: You're using JavaScript - you can change anything you want.

Comment: the situation is different here as this form is submitted on different events that are binded to buttons (fiddle just illustrates this as dummy with sample form) and i can't manipulate the buttons or dom for this.